# XAF, Getting values from caller of the popup window

Tags: devexpress, xaf

Here is just a simple example of my code

```
[DefaulClassOptions]
class APerson : XPObject
{
  private int data;
  public int Data {
   get{ return data; } set { SetPropertyValue("Data", ref data, value); }
  }

  [Action(Caption = "Get Data")]
      public void getData(myClass mclass)
      {
          this.Data = mclass.Data2;
      }
}

class myClass
{
  private int data2;
  public int Data2 {
   get; set;
  }
}
```

Now, everything works fine. Clicking the "Get Data" button opens up a popup and prompts for the field. I wanted to know that if there is a way through which I can send data from APerson class to the popup window so that it displays data value if it has been set previously.

Comment: I blogged this back in 2010 http://apobekiaris.blogspot.gr/2010/03/xaf-tip-12-how-to-pass-parameters.html

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible when using the ActionAttribute, which is designed for simple cases only. For more complex scenarios, use a ViewController with a [PopupWindowShowAction](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument2723) and access the current View object information as per [this XAF documentation article](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#Xaf/CustomDocument3324).

Comment: I used the following code for popWindowParams function:

e.View = Application.CreateDetailView(objectSpace, Application.FindDetailViewId(typeof(myClass)), true);

but it does not display in edit mode so I can enter my values.

Comment: I changed the code but still cannot enter data, the fields are disabled

DetailView dv = Application.CreateDetailView(objectSpace, Application.FindDetailViewId(typeof(myClass)), true);
            dv.ViewEditMode = ViewEditMode.Edit;
            e.View = dv;

Comment: You cannot enter any data because there is no MyClass object set for this DetailView. Either use another overload or set the DetailView.CurrentObject property directly.

P.S.
I recommend you use the official DevExpress support channel to get a faster assistance with DevExpress-related questions: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create

Comment: yes thankyou I figured it out later instead of "Application.FindDetailViewId(typeof(myClass))" I had to enter an istance of myClass.